# Does losing an ssh session kills commands running in tmux?

Tags: ssh, tmux

The question I know is basic, but could not find an exact matching question in community.
The standard process of using tmux is - create a session, run command within and then detach the session. So existing ssh terminal will not kill our process.

My question is, if tmux session is created and a long command is running within it. But **before detaching, if ssh session terminates, then will this tmux session persist or it will be killed too**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically after losing an ssh connection the child process will receive a `SIGHUP`. This signal causes `tmux` to detach itself from the lossen ssh session.

So tmux's session will stay persistent on a remote machine even if ssh session gets terminated.

---

Test it yourself:

1. Open a terminal and run `tmux`.
2. In your "tmux" session run `sleep 100`.
3. Open another terminal and run: `pkill -1 tmux`.

   - Now tmux has been closed in the first terminal.
4. Run `tmux ls` to see that your sessions is still there.

   - Or `tmux attach` to bring it up.

<sub>I have also tested the actual losing ssh session scenario on a remote machine, result is the same.</sub>