# I can launch a Perl script with cron, but can I make it open up a window?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, perl, output

I have an Perl script that runs all night, through a terminal window (Win10 putty.exe) on my Ubuntu server. As with many home networks, I occasionally lose my internet connection, which kills my connection and the script.

Running another Perl script through cron (which checks if my script is running), I am able to restart the Perl script.

However it is running without a window.

Is there a method that when I putty into Ubuntu, I can open a terminal window that shows the output from my Perl script which is now running?

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem - perhaps what you really need is to run the script in a terminal multiplexer session (using `screen` or `tmux`) so that you can re-attach to it if the original connection is lost? See for example [Does losing an ssh session kills commands running in tmux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161966/does-losing-an-ssh-session-kills-commands-running-in-tmux)

Comment: A good practice is to store your scheduled scripts output to a log file then send it via email. You wont have to check the host for an open window...

Comment: cron jobs do not know for which user they run, even less if that user is logged in, even more less what window the user prefers that job to connect to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output from the cron script to a file >> /path/filename.log

Or start the script with screen: screen -Sdm perl /path/to/script.pl

Comment: The thing is, cron might restarts the script on the server. My PC might have been disconnected from my server for hours.  Is there a command the cron can start the perl script with a command that a later time I can find the pid for the job and screen to it? I know very little when it comes to this OS. I'm lucky I was able to actually make a sever for myself by Googling as I went on.

Comment: The -S option in screen means sessionname. So when you reconnect use screen -r sessionname. You can also screen -list to get all the sessions running.

Comment: Found this cool video on how to use screen on YT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3txYaF_IVZQ

Answer (score 1):

Run the script in `screen`, ie. before you start the script, type `screen` (if you get "command not found", you need first to install the `screen` package). It will just display system prompt as if nothing has changed, but since now you got a virtual terminal that survives loss of your connection. Script will continue to run in that terminal even when you disconnect.

When you lose connection, after reconnecting to your server, type `screen -ls`. This will list your `screen` sessions. The output can look like this:

```
There is a screen on:
    19923.pts-10.myserver   (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-myuser.
```

("myserver" and "myuser" will be your actual hostname and username respectively). If you see "Detached" as above, it means that server correctly noticed that connection was lost and the session has been properly disconnected. In that case, you can reattach to that session with the command:

```
screen -r 19923
```

where of course the number 19923 is the PID of the `screen` process that you got from the `screen -ls` command.

However, it might be that the server did not notice disconnection and your `screen` session is still "Attached" to the session that no longer exists. In that case you need first disconnect your `screen` session before re-attaching to it, you can do this by specifying additionally the `-d` parameter:

```
screen -d -r 19923
```

That is a commonly used and de facto standard solution for running programs that should be protected from accidental closing of terminal session and continue to run even if that happens.

When your script finishes and returns to OS, then first `exit` command typed at the OS prompt will termninate `screen` and return you back to regular terminal session (you will see a message "screen is terminating"). The second `exit` command will log you out.